# Applying css based on the existence of a page in mediawiki

Tags: css, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates, mediawiki-extensions

I'm working on a process for transcribing and translating documents that combines [Extension:Proofread Page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aProofread_Page) and [Extension:Translate](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aExtension%3aTranslate). Proofread Page applies different background colors to each link in the list based on the page status (scan uploaded, transcribed, proofread, etc.), and I'd like to extend that to apply to translation as well.

Changing the background color is simple enough using a template like this:

```
[[page:{{{1|}}}|<span style="background-color:#48d1cc;">{{{2|}}}</span>]]
```

The trouble is making it contingent on the existence of an English translation, which would be stored at `{{PAGENAME}}/en`. This `#ifexist:` function solves that problem:

```
{{#ifexist: page:{{{1|}}}/en
  | [[page:{{{1|}}}|<span style="background-color:#48d1cc;">{{{2|}}}</span>]]
  | [[page:{{{1|}}}|{{{2|}}}]]
}}
```

But `#ifexist` is classified as an "expensive" parser function and limited to 100 per page, whereas I have some indexes with upwards of 700 links.

Obviously I can just require that the first template I mentioned be manually invoked for each page as a translation is created (i.e. replacing `[[page: ]]` with `{{page| }}` in the index one link at a time), but I'd prefer a fire-and-forget solution that I can use when I initially create each index.

---

So is there either

1. A way to exceed the expensive parser function cap in mediawiki?
2. Some trick for applying conditional css in this situation without invoking `#ifexist`?

Or, I guess,

1. An easy hack for Extension:Proofread Page that would solve this problem?

   MediaWiki: 1.19.2
   Semantic MediaWiki: 1.8 beta 1
   PHP: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 (apache2handler)
   MySQL: 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can raise the cap by bumping [$wgExpensiveParserFunctionLimit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgExpensiveParserFunctionLimit) in LocalSettings.php.

Comment: Brilliant. Is there a reason not to set this cap arbitrarily high? (Public editing is disabled and all users are known project members.)

Comment: @MichaelChidester Page parsing will be slow if you use them a lot, so the problem lies with public viewing, rather that public editing. They offer an opportunity for DDoS'ing you, for instance